# Facebook Tagged Places>are these tags posted in real-time or delayed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, tags

Anyone have experience as to the “average time” the tagged places are posted?

This reference link below does explain > “Tagged places are aggregated to within the closest 12 hours, so this endpoint does not provide a complete list of all items that would result in a tagged place”. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/tagged_places/

Also, where are they posted?

And how is this “Place Tag” different from “Tagged Places”?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/place-tag/

Comment: _“Also, where are they posted?”_ – what do you mean by that? “A list of tags of this person at a place in a photo, video, post, status or link” – that’s where they are “posted” – in photos, videos, posts, etc. And the second one is the structure of the items that you will get back from the first endpoint.

Comment: As for your question title, _“are these tags posted in real-time or delayed”_ – the _posts_ themselves, that include place information and tagged the user, are in real-time – only the _list_ of such places that the user was tagged in might be updated in a delayed fashion (probably for performance reasons.)

Comment: U have been extremely helpful, you also answered my other question "Need to Receive alert only when a “location” is posted with users update status from Facebook Graph API".

Comment: @cbroe  So our server cannot receive the users "tagged places" in real-time, only when posted to list whenever that may be?

Comment: Again: They do not get “posted” _to_ that list, they get posted in the normal places – posts, videos, photos etc. This list is only an aggregation of those types in which the user was tagged – and they _show up_ in this list delayed.

Comment: Ok, I finally understand the "list" concept. So the "tagged places" will not return real-time info we need. Then, your answer to my other post>>Need to Receive alert only when a “location” is posted with users update status from Facebook Graph API, is the way to get real-time location info when filtered.